# Trying to print a txt File as a hard copy with Python

Tags: python, printing, python-import

I'm trying to get print out using python code snippet given below.

```
import os
file_path = 'sheet.txt'
os.startfile(file_path, "print")
```

but its gives me the blow error

> [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file
> for this operation: 'sheet.txt'

Please let me what us mistake that I'm doing. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Have you tried to pass absoulte file path?

Comment: Pass the complete path of your ```sheet.txt``` file

Comment: i tried the passing absolute path, but no luck